# Upgrading to ServiceStack 2.0 breaks /types/typescript rendering

Tags: servicestack

When upgrading from ServiceStack 5.0.3 to 5.2 and then attempting to generate TypeScript DTOs the following example was rendered

```
// @Route("/boms/{sortColumn}/{sortAscending}", "GET")
export class GetUserLists implements IReturn<UserListModel[]>
{
    public sortColumn: number;
    public sortAscending: boolean;
    public createResponse() { return Array<UserListModel>; }
    public getTypeName() { return 'GetUserLists'; }
}
```

instead of something like this:

```
// @Route("/boms/{sortColumn}/{sortAscending}", "GET")
export class GetUserLists implements IReturn<Array<UserListModel>>
{
    sortColumn: number;
    sortAscending: boolean;
    createResponse() { return Array<UserListModel>(); }
    getTypeName() { return 'GetUserLists'; }
}
```

It's the missing () that causes the syntax error.

When I reverted back to ServiceStack 5.0.3,the generated dtos.ts was correct and compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/2f681afa8c8579d0c792177058bf32c2561515ea), this change is available from v5.2.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).